# Identify (Oneself) As

Tags: meaning

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*identify*" [here](https://gma.yahoo.com/charleston-shooting-suspects-childhood-friend-details-upbringing-163623707--abc-news-topstories.html):

> Caleb Brown, ***who identifies as half-black***, said he went to elementary and middle school with Dylann Roof, the 21-year-old accused of killing nine people inside Emanuel AME Church in Charleston, South Carolina, on Wednesday.

I checked several dictionaries and the closest usage pattern that fits the current example is "*identify oneself as*".  The pattern "*identify as*" could not be found.  So, is the example sentence in the article wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's idiomatic among (American, at least) minorities to say that they "identify as" some distinct minority group if they consider themselves similar enough to their own definition of that group to qualify. It's related to the usage of "identify with" to indicate empathy with someone else, where one can draw from one's own experiences to feel essentially the same way someone else does.

The usage is deliberately subjective; someone who "identifies as" some minority may or may not appear to be classically a part of that group to others. For example, someone who appears to be Caucasian but has a certain amount of Cherokee ancestry may "identify as" Cherokee. Occasionally someone will "identify as" a member of some group that is not traditionally a minority: male, for example, or an animal or alien.

This can be seen on [wiktionary (the sixth sense)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/identify).